# SharePoint2010 is it possible to set an alert on change to column?

Tags: 2010, development, list, alert, libraries

I have a user that would like alerts when specific columns in a list are changed. Is this possible OOTB or does it require some C#? If it requires some custom code, does anyone have resources to use as a starting point?

Example:

Column A is a percentage, as a project progresses, the percentage is updated by a a team member. I would like an alert to the project manager that the specific field in the list item was changed.

Comment: Are you talking about if the column itself is renamed or if (if it's a choice column) if an option is added? Or are you talking about if that column is changed in any list item?

Comment: Sorry that wasn't clear, heres an example:
Column A is a percentage, as a project progresses, the percentage is updated by a a team member. I would like an alert to the project manager that the specific field in the list item was changed.

Comment: Please use commenting rather than answering if you have any clarifications on the Question

Comment: Whoops, sorry about that, should have commented.

Comment: @RJarvis, you should always add clarification of the question to the question itself. I've edited your question, but sometimes people won't see comments to answers or answers could be deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing OOTB that I know of.  I can think of 2 options and they both essentially do the same thing.

**Customer Event Receiver** -- you need to use the ItemUpdating event which isn't overly painful if you're familiar with sharepoint event receivers.  This should help --

[Item Updating Event Receiver](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/4777209f-eaf7-40c0-a81f-d090bc405134/event-receiver-c-code-did-column-value-change?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious)

The downfall is now you want to alert someone so you need to add to your custom code or you could also create a sharepoint designer workflow that only emails people and call that through your code.  This isn't an easy way to go, to be honest.  If you're not familiar with event receivers and haven't done much development within sharepoint, I'd go for the below.  If you are somewhat familiar, I've actually this exact scenario and can find and share what I did if you like.

**Sharepoint Designer workflow**
You could also create a workflow that does the same thing as above and is a little more user friendly if others need to work on it later.

1. Create a second column in your list.... ColumnAOriginal
2. Create a new list worflow that runs on new and edited items
3. Add a condition that says if ColumnAOriginal is not blank AND ColumnAOriginal is not equal to ColumnA, send an email.  Below that, setup your email.
4. Add an action below that copies Column A to ColumnAOriginal

We looked to see if ColumnAOriginal is blank because in all new items, it will always be blank as the workflow has not run yet.

Answer (score 1):

OOTB Alerts does not have the flexibility to be called only when the particular field in list item is changed , rather it will be called when any field in the list item is changed. You can create similar functionality with 2 approaches :

1. Create an Event receiver which will be called on item updating.Compare before properties and after properties value of that field , if it is different send email using [SPUtility.SendEmail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.sendemail.aspx).

2.Create another field say Percentage_old which stores previous value.Create a designer List workflow which will compare the 2 fields , if current value is NOT EQUAL to old value, Send Email and Set the Old value=Current Value. Set the Workflow to run on Item updated.
See this for [Send Email using Workflow](http://sp365.co.uk/2011/07/create-an-email-with-sharepoint-designer/)

Comment: Unnie and I pretty much said the same thing.